# How do I store a 16 byte binary value that can be represented as a 32 hexadecimal characters in an unsigned char* variable in C

Tags: c, binary, hex

I have this variable `unsigned char* key`

How do I store a 16 byte binary value that can be represented as 32 hexadecimal characters into this variable?

I have tried:

```
#define SECRET { 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b}
unsigned char* key = SECRET;
```

Not sure if this is correct.

Comment: Hi I have tried this
`#define SECRET { 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b}`
`unsigned char *key= SECRET;`

Not sure if this is correct

Answer (score 1):

```
#define SECRET { 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b}
unsigned char* key = SECRET;
```

is not correct. You can use:

```
#define SECRET { 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b}
unsigned char key[] = SECRET;  // Change key to an array.
```

If you must you use a pointer, you can create two variables.

```
#define SECRET { 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b}
unsigned char key_array[] = SECRET;
unsigned char* key =  key_array;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Does this mean SECRET is defined as a null 16 byte binary value?

Comment: @user3419585, Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @user3419585, you are storing those bytes in `key`.

Comment: @R Sahu. Sorry I know I'm being very stupid but am I storing null bytes in `key`?

Comment: @user3419585, no you are not storing null bytes in `key`. `key[0] = 0x0b`. `key[1] = 0x0b`, etc.